# How to force virtualenv to install latest setuptools and pip from pypi?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip, setuptools, virtualenvwrapper

Is it possible to force virtualenv to use the latest setuptools and pip available from pypi?  Essentially, I'm looking for the ***opposite*** of the `--never-download` flag.

Currently, when I make a new virtualenv, it uses the local (old) versions that come bundled with virtualenv.

```
$ v.mk testvenv
New python executable in testvenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools............done.
Installing pip...............done.
$ pip show setuptools
---
Name: setuptools
Version: 0.6c11
Location: /Users/cwilson/.virtualenvs/testvenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Requires: 
$ pip search setuptools
[...]
setuptools                - Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and
                            uninstall Python packages
INSTALLED: 0.6c11
LATEST:    0.7.2
[...]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not supported for security reasons.

> Using virtualenv.py as an isolated script (i.e. without an associated
>   virtualenv_support directory) is no longer supported for security
>   reasons and will fail with an error. Along with this, --never-download
>   is now always pinned to True, and is only being maintained in the
>   short term for backward compatibility (Pull #412).

I can't use the `--extra-search-dir` option either because it's currently broken https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/327

Looks like the only option is to simply wait for the virtualenv maintainers to update the bundled packages?

Answer (score 9):

You can upgrade pip after installing your virtualenv by using `pip install -U pip`.

I'm sure you could write a bootstrap-script to automate this step.

Answer (score 4):

I needed the latest setuptools library, and the `--extra-search-dir` flag wasn't working for me (even though it's been fixed apparently).

However, making a virtualenv without setuptools and then installing directly from PyPi worked great.
E.g. to set up a virtualenv called `test`:

```
virtualenv --no-setuptools test
source test/bin/activate
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
easy_install pip
```

Testing with

```
python -c 'import setuptools; print setuptools.__version__'
```

shows the right version.

Comment: very nice solution!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, and I fixed it by upgrading `setuptools`.

If `env` is your virtual env, run the following:

`$ env/bin/pip install --upgrade setuptools`

Answer (score 0):

Building on ematsen's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34696823/2407209) I made a bash script that works with virtualenvwrapper

```
#!/bin/bash
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
mkvirtualenv --no-setuptools $1
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | python
rm setuptools-*.zip
easy_install pip

# for python version < 2.7.9
# https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
pip install urllib3[secure]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that.

```
virtualenv -p python3 --download my-env
```

Then virtualenv puts the latest packages.

```
my-env/bin/pip list
```

Out:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.2.1
setuptools 68.2.2
wheel      0.41.2
```

Info:

```
------download    pass to enable download of the latest pip/setuptools/wheel from PyPI (default: False)
```

More info:

```
virtualenv --help
```