# Difference in version of setuptools with virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools, easy-install

Here's my Windows setup

- `c:\Python27` : installed via official msi
- `setuptools` : installed via `python setup.py install` (from: [setuptools-1.1.5.tar.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-1.1.5.tar.gz))
- `pip`               : installed via `python get-pip.py`             (from [get-pip.py](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py))
- `virtualenv` : installed via `python setup.py install` (from : [virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.10.1.tar.gz))
- Create virtualenv using : `virtualenv --no-site-packages myenv`

Now, `setuptools` shows a different version in the following 2 cases :

1. Open a shell & run `pip list`:
   pip (1.4.1)
   setuptools (**1.1.5**)
   virtualenv (1.10.1)
2. `activate` virtualenv & run pip list
   pip (1.4.1)
   setuptools (**0.9.8**)

Why is `setuptool` showing version 0.9.8 in virtualenv although I installed version 1.1.5 as shown in the global path?

**Update:**

I tried @Rod's suggestion and it worked. But my setup broke. I wish the caveat was mentioned in the answer. I'm adding this here so that others don't end up wasting hours like I did. If I use the option `--no-setuptools` while creating virtualenv, after activating virtualenv, pip installs the packages globally.

My project had some dependencies that were installed via `pip install`. They stopped working (i.e. MySQLdb adapter). When I created another virtualenv without the `--no-setuptools` option, it started working.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed?

Comment: No, just Python 2.7. Clean install

Comment: Same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156912/how-to-force-virtualenv-to-install-latest-setuptools-and-pip-from-pypi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is setuptool showing version 0.9.8 in virtualenv although I
>   installed version 1.1.5 as shown in the global path?

The different setuptools version seen is due to virtualenv bundling a version of setuptools within its archive (version 1.10.1 is bundled with setuptools 0.9.8). The local setuptools is installed from the archive to avoid accessing the network.

Having a different version of setuptools in your virtualenv should not be a problem.

**Changing the version**

If you must change the version, currently there is no way to force downloading another version setuptools other than unpacking the tar file and replacing the setuptools archive, in `virtualenv-1.10.1\virtualenv_support` with a newer version.

Eventually you will be able to specify a directory containing another version of setuptools to use, with the [`--extra-search-dir`](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#the-extra-search-dir-option) option, but the feature currently does not work.

*Note:* Virtualenv will install its own version of setuptools if you do not specify `--no-setuptools` when you create your virtualenv. Obviously, using the option `--no-setuptools` will not install setuptools nor pip. It will most likely break the encapsulation provided by virtualenv (as the OP noted).

Comment: I wonder why doesn't it check for an existing setuptools package before overriding with an older version. Is there any downside of using `--no-setuptools` when I already have it globally?

Comment: Updated to answer to be clearer that `--no-setuptools` was provided as information not as a solution.