# ImportError: No module named virtualenv

Tags: python, django, windows-7

I am using Django 1.3.7 and python 2.7.6 on windows7
I got an error when I executing my manage.py in this line of code

```
import shutil, sys, virtualenv, subprocess
```

amd running it, I got this error

```
C:\Django-Proj\>python manage.py update_ve
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    import shutil, sys, virtualenv, subprocess
ImportError: No module named virtualenv
```

Does anyone have an Idea about my case?

Comment: Looks like Django `manage.py` requires that `virtualenv` is installed. Have you got it installed?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Install virtualenv using `pip install virtualenv`.
If you have it already installed, try reinstalling it by removing it with `pip uninstall virtualenv` and then reinstalling it. 
Good Luck.

Comment: This worked for me on OS X using the MacPorts Python. Although MacPorts includes ports for `virtualenv` and `virtualenvwrapper`, they are outdated. So `pip` bundled with `virtualenv` is outdated, mandating uninstalling the MacPorts one and using `pip` to install the latest `virtualenv`. For details, for any MacPorts users that run into the same issue, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17156912/how-to-force-virtualenv-to-install-latest-setuptools-and-pip-from-pypi).

Comment: On ubuntu, I noticed that even pip install vitualenv is successful, when I execute the command to create one, it keeps saying there's no virtualenv installed and suggesting use apt to install. Should I give it a try?

Comment: Also found I had a subborn /usr/local/bin/virtualenv binary that wouldn't delete via pip uninstall, so a sudo rm -f on that did the trick, then did a normal user pip install and finally got things to work.

Comment: Works perfectly :D

Comment: @Shad, on Ubuntu, it probably defaults to python3, so try: `sudo pip3 install virtualenv`

Comment: `pip install virtualenv` [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663774/how-to-install-virtualenv-for-python2-7). `pip uninstall virtualenv` also doesn't work: pip says "Cannot uninstall requirement virtualenv, not installed".

Answer (score 22):

I had to install virtualenv with the -H flag to set HOME variable to target user's home dir.

`sudo -H pip install virtualenv`

Comment: `sudo pip install virtualenv` (with no `-H`) worked for me on KDE neon 5.26 .

Answer (score 13):

Use pip3 instead of pip. I had the same issue and pip3 worked for me.

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
$ virtualenv venv --python=python3
```

Comment: I didn't have pip on my system, and working with pip3 did the trick.

Answer (score 13):

Try

```sh
python3 -m pip uninstall virtualenv
```

```sh
python3 -m pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: It works, while what's the difference between `pip3 uninstall virtualenv` and `python3 -m pip uninstall virtualenv`?

Answer (score 12):

I think the problem is you need `sudo` to globally install virtualenv.

```
> pip install virtualenv
Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
> sudo pip install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
...
```

But this creates files readable only by root (depending on the umask).
In this case, uninstalling/reinstalling may not always help.

You can check with `ls -la /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py` (replacing 2.7 with whatever version you have or are targeting).

My solution was simply:

```
sudo chmod -R o+rX /usr/local/lib/python2.7
```

Comment: This worked for me. In my case `virtualenv` was installed as root; but not accessible by another unprivileged user

Comment: I had this error, 
`No module named 'virtualenv.seed'; 'virtualenv' is not a package`
This solution worked for me, virtualenv was installed as a root, but it did not work for some reason until I changed the chmod as mentioned above.

Answer (score 5):

I just ran into this same problem. I had to `pip uninstall virtualenv` as a user with admin rights, then `pip install virtualenv` as a normal user. I think it's some kind of permissions issue if you installed virtualenv under admin rights.

Answer (score 1):

For mac os the issue was with virtualenv. This is because the folder virtualenv did not exist.

This worked well

> `python3 -m venv env`

Answer (score 0):

```
>virtualenv
ImportError: No module named 'virtualenv'
>pip uninstall virtualenv
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

>sudo pip uninstall virtualenv
Successfully uninstalled virtualenv-15.1.0
>pip install virtualenv
Collecting virtualenv

>virtualenv
Options:
```

Bingo!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I created my virtualenv via pycharm and installed requirements with pycharm.
After trail and error , I found that installed requirements are not taken into account by the virtualenv.

The solution is to reinstall all requirements once you have activated your virtualenv:

> venv\scripts\activate
>
> python -m pip install -r YourRequirements.txt

Next time I'd better create my virtualenv directly with command line

Answer (score 0):

Got this error when using the ansible pip module automating some pip installs on my localhost.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "cmd": ["/opt/bin/virtualenv", "--system-site-packages", "-p/usr/bin/python3", "/opt/venv/myenv"], "msg": "\n:stderr: /usr/bin/python3: No module named  virtualenv\n"}
```

Uninstalling virtualenv `python3 -m pip uninstall virtualenv` did show `virtualenv` was installed here `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/virtualenv`.

In the ansible task specify the `virtualenv_command`:

```
- name: install requirements file
  pip:
    virtualenv_command: "/home/{{whoami.stdout}}/.local/bin/virtualenv"
    virtualenv: "/home/{{whoami.stdout}}/.venv/{{item.env.virtualenv}}"
    requirements: "/home/{{whoami.stdout}}/git/{{item.env.requirements_txt}}"
    virtualenv_site_packages: yes
  when: req_stat.stat.exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Poetry wants to be in venv by default so I used venv in docker. I got the error randomly after multiple month of using that setup.

If this is the case for you, just don't use venv in docker. You can turn off venv requirement for poetry by: `/usr/bin/poetry config virtualenvs.create false`.

It is also possible to export poetry into requirements.txt by `poetry export -f requirements.txt --output requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

### sudo apt install python3-virtualenv

worked for me: (WSL env)

`sudo apt install python3-virtualenv`